# How can I position views inside the constraints of another view and relative to their boundaries in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In an Android app I am making I have a ListView which uses custom rows designed in a separate xml file, and in this xml file I need to position a TextView and two buttons in the boundaries of an ImageView, and this is hard to do because since the ImageView is not a parent to the buttons/textview I'm not sure how to position them perfectly. Here is an image of the listView and how I want the custom rows to look:

[image: Click here]

Here is the xml I whipped up so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gameImageID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/overwatch" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gameNameID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gameNameID"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnJoinLobby"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="myClickHandlerJoin"
            android:text="Join Lobby"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateLobby"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="myClickHandlerCreate"
            android:text="Create Lobby"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This produces this though:

[image: Click here]

As you can see the buttons are not exactly where I want them. When I move them any further down on the image they shoot to the bottom of the screen because it aligns it to the bottom of its parent, which is the size of the whole screen. How can I make this so if I align it to the bottom of something it'll just go to the bottom of the image?

Also bonus question: How can I add that black bar behind the TexView at the top of the row in the concept image? I would like to do so with code so it can stay relative to the size of the image, for if I make the black bar an image it'll be constrained to that one size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the buttons in an relative layout...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gameImageID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/overwatch" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gameNameID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gameNameID"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnJoinLobby"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="myClickHandlerJoin"
            android:text="Join Lobby" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateLobby"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="myClickHandlerCreate"
            android:text="Create Lobby" />


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```